# how append date build to versionNameSuffix on gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio and I need to append a suffix to the `versionNameSuffix` on my Android *build.gradle* file. I have three different build types and I only need to append the datetime to my "beta" release. My actual file is:

```groovy
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 14
    versionName "0.7.5"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
buildTypes {
    beta {
        packageNameSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    ....
}
```

For testing and automatic deploy, I need to get a final versionName like: `0.7.5-beta-build20131004`, `0.7.5-beta-build1380855996` or something like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```groovy
beta {
    packageNameSuffix ".beta"
    versionNameSuffix "-beta" + "-build" + getDate()
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}

def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
    return formattedDate
}
```

Condensed:

```
def getDate() {
    return new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
}
```

Comment: How to generate apk after configed the build.gradle?

Comment: como generar el apk despues?

Answer (score 40):

You can define in your build.gradle custom functions and variables.

```groovy
def versionMajor = 3

def buildTime() {
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") // you can change it
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    return df.format(new Date())
}
```

Then you can use it:

```groovy
android {
    defaultConfig {
       versionName "${versionMajor}-beta-build-${buildTime()}"
    }
}
```

or if you want to add it in you versionNameSuffix

```groovy
beta {
    versionNameSuffix "-beta-build-${buildTime()}"      
}
```

Comment: versionNameSuffix has been broken for at least a year

Comment: `buildTime` is underlined: Inner methods are not supported.

Comment: how do you get Date() imported?

Answer (score 9):

Also, do not forget to add import as Gradle first line:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
...
```

Comment: or avoid the grief and use Date().format("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ")

Answer (score 5):

```
for simple one row solution define this property above android section 

final BUILD_DATE = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HHmm')

and then 

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId APPLICATION_ID
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        versionName GIT_TAG_NAME
        versionCode GIT_COMMIT_COUNT
        setProperty("archivesBaseName",`enter code here` "com-appname-$BUILD_DATE-$versionName")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
// At the top of the file
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.*

// ...

android {
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") { // OR simply  debug {  in newer versions of Android Gradle Plugin (AGP)
            val date = LocalDate.now().toString()
            // OR val date = LocalDate.now().format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            // OR val date = LocalDate.now().format(ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            versionNameSuffix = date
        }
    }
}
```

You could also extract the date creation to a function:

```kotlin
android {
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            versionNameSuffix = generateDate()
        }
    }
}

fun generateDate() = LocalDate.now().toString()
// OR fun generateDate() = LocalDate.now().format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
// OR fun generateDate() = LocalDate.now().format(ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but I'll assume Gradle behaves as it normally does. Adding something like this to your build project configuration should do the trick:

```groovy
allProjects {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        versionNameSuffix += '-build' + // Java/Groovy code to produce the timestamp formatted the way you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test

```
task timenow {
    println(new Date().getTime())
}
```

Run gradle: gradle timenow

See details. Place it on the top-level build

```
ext {
    configuration = [
            appName          : "vBulletin",
            applicationId    : "com.vbulletin",
            minSdkVersion    : 14,
            targetSdkVersion : 19,
            compileSdkVersion: 19,
            versionCode      : 6,
            versionName      : "1.3.6",
            buildToolsVersion: "25.0.0",
    ]

}

task createBrand {
    appConfig.applicationId = appConfig.applicationId + ".${brand}"
    appConfig.versionCode = new Date().getTime()
    appConfig.versionName = version
}
```