# How to access apk generated time in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, dynamically-generated, build-time

Is it possible to get generated time of APK  programmatically?

I want to display that on the build time for build identification purposes.

I know that I could hard code the time string in the gradle file and access them in my Kotlin code, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/4620609) answer suggests, But that would mean every time I've to change the string when I re-generate the build.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: call something like System.currentTime (pseudocode) in your build.gradle so you don't manually have to change the value

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172565/how-append-date-build-to-versionnamesuffix-on-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code in build.gradle file to achieve this

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILT_ON", "\"${getBuildDateTime()}\""
        }
    }
}

static def getBuildDateTime() {
    return "Build Generated On: ${new Date().format("dd MMMM, 2018 @ h:mma")}"
}
```

Now I can access this variable in my Activity

```
Log.d(BuildConfig.BUILT_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in **`defaultConfig`** of your project to set up your application build time.

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Application_Name_$versionName.$versionCode" + "_" + getDate())

static def getDate() {
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MMM-dd_EEE_HH.mm')
return formattedDate
}
```